# Facebook count using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, facebook

I have a problem with getting number of shares of my custom url. Im trying this code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.myurl.com/somelink/?callback=?",
    processData: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(r){
      var fbjson = JSON.stringify(r);
      console.log(fbjson);
    }
  });
```

I've tried also:

```
$.getJSON('http://graph.facebook.com/https://www.myurl.com/somelink/?cal‌​lback=?'), function (data) {

fbjson = JSON.stringify(fbjson);

console.log(fbjson);


 };
```

When I paste url into browser I recieving JSON with all needed information, but when I am using `$.ajax` etc. I am recieving totaly different json or some error that I should use `XMLHttpRequest` or some other serwer status information. Important knowladge may be that I am using `https://`.

Anyone know how to correctly get FB share count for custom URL ?

PS Be understanding for me, this are my first steps in JS, thanks :)

Comment: Did you try change "http" to "https"?

Comment: Those API calls need an access token. So you either need to make the visitor of your website login to your Facebook app first, so that you can use their user access token; or you have to do this on the server side, where you can use your app access token or a page access token (both of which must never be exposed in client-side code.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solve it. This script work correctly ;)

```
(function fbcount() {

  var token = 'token here',
  url = 'url here';

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.7/',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, id: url},
    success: function(data){
      $('.facebook-scount').append(data.share.share_count);
    },
    error: function(data){
    }
  });

  })();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For the json might be cooke issue. your browser have cookie for that URL but in ajax you need to pass that cookie !

Why you are counting share count manually ? 
There is lots of share tools is available for fee !

example : http://js-socials.com/

I think this plugin will give you what you need !

Thanks